# How to import text file from different folder?

Tags: python

I have my project folder `\FNAL PROJ\project`
and I need to open `file.txt` from folder `\FNAL PROJ\project\data`

How to do it in Python?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your main script is somewhere on \FNAL PROJ\project folder:

```
with open("data/file.txt", "r") as f:
    file_content = f.read()
```

Comment: Yes, use the read() method, more info here http://docs.python.org/2.4/lib/bltin-file-objects.html

Comment: Can i use some thing like : file=open("data/file.txt", "r") ?

Comment: Yep, feel free, but remember to close the file (file.close()) once you have read it, because other programs won't be able to open the file while it's open. As I don't want to remember to close the file, I use with statement.